# How to set up an analog to digital converter like parallel TLC0820AC, to convert input voltage (volts and tenths) into a BCD?

Tags: adc

[image]

I would like to use an AD chip to convert the input voltage into two digits - volts and tenths. Such a simple voltmeter. Unfortunately, I don't know how to set the input voltage to get an error-free scale of the 0-10V conversion. I have tried to use a triple voltage divider but it only works fine for volts (one LED).

Comment: Your meter would probably work in hexadecimal with a decimal point in the middle. Then you would have voltages reading from 0.0 to F.F volts. The problem is that you are trying to convert an 8-bit readout to two decimal digits. I don't think there is an easy fix other than using a microcontroller.

Comment: What do you mean by "error-free" - can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: if I set the correct input voltage using the potentiometer for the one input voltage (so that it points to 5.3V), it does not work for other input voltages. The reading value is different from the next input voltage value. I have no experience with digital electronics so my explanation may be inaccurate. Sorry about that.

Comment: Binary to BCD converter IC : see the TTL Databook.

Comment: @Brian Drummond Thanks, it's 74185 chip. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there are lots of codes output by the ADC that aren't valid BCD because they're the hex numbers A-F.

The normal solution is "use a microcontroller", but I think there might be some binary-to-BCD or analogue-to-display converter chips in the 74LS catalogue?